# why are my network settings inside of my VM different than my host pc? How is it still establishing a connection?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

My default gateway is 10.12.1.1, but on my VM its showing my gateway as 10.0.2.2.

I tried setting my gateway to 10.12.1.1 and I lost internet.

And then I tried to open a browser and visit 10.0.2.2 but it wouldn't load anything, but when I went to 10.12.1.1 in my VM it loaded my router.

How is it loading 10.12.1.1 when the default gateway is 10.0.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Bridged Adapter in the Network Settings in VirtualBox in order to get the same network settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What VM software are you using? Many VM applications use network address translation by default. The way this works is that from the VM's perspective, the VM software creates a virtual gateway between the VM and the network that your host PC is connected to. Often, the IP of this virtual gateway will be in the 10.X.X.X range because this range is [reserved for local communications in private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#IPv4).

In this case, the reason why the local gateway of your VM would be set to a different local gateway from your host PC is because there is a virtual gateway between the VM and your network. Of course, the VM is still connected to your network (indirectly via the virtual gateway), so it can see everything on your network including the physical gateway on your network. However, since it's not directly connected to the physical gateway (because its traffic goes through the virtual gateway), you can't set the VM's gateway to the same gateway as your physical network.

If you try to do it anyway, what will happen is that your computer will try to find the MAC address of the physical gateway which it would need in order to send ethernet packets directly to it (as opposed to through a different gateway). However, the broadcasts that the VM sends to try to learn the MAC address will be dropped because the VM isn't on the same local network since there is a virtual gateway in the way. Furthermore, even if the VM knew the MAC address of the physical gateway, it wouldn't be able to send ethernet packets directly to it because it isn't on the same local network. Instead, it has to send ethernet packets to the virtual gateway which then forwards them wherever they need to go.